# Problem installing beyond compare on 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I have a problem while installing Beyond Compare on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS config.

I follow the instructions [Linux Installation Instructions](http://goo.gl/c500Ev)

but when I issue the last command here's what I get :

```
Traitement déclenché pour  libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...   

sudo gdebi bcompare-4.1.1.20615_amd64.deb
gdebi error, file not found: bcompare-4.1.1.20615_amd64.deb
```

I cannot understand what I did wrong.

Comment: Could be wrong file name or location.

Comment: have you downloaded `.deb` ?....download from [here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php)

Answer (score 2):

First the download, than the installation

Download the deb file [here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php) and install or use the steps below

```
cd
wget http://www.scootersoftware.com/bcompare-4.1.1.20615_amd64.deb
sudo -H gdebi bcompare-4.1.1.20615_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks A.B that worked perfectly. I must have been very tired not looking properly on the scootersoftware.com site.